# Onvif two way Audio tcp

Tags: audio, tcp, stream, onvif

does someone know if it possible two stream two way Audio via TCP from an onvif device/Server?

NOT via rtsp backchannel!

And if someone knows this, how Do I implement this?

Thanks

Comment: The RTSP backchannel is the only supported way. Anything else would be vendor specific. Why not implement the RTSP backhannel?

Comment: Because it is not possible to implement backchannel at the moment because the rtsp stream is kind of a hack but thanks for the reply :)